# NSData dataWithContentsOfURL returns nil

Tags: nsdata

I am trying to fetch a XML file from a URL and store it locally, yet I find the `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL xxxx]` returns nil to me. 
The error message reads: `operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)`

Could you help to review my code and point to me the problem:

```
NSError* err = nil;
NSString* urlString = @"http://www.w3school.com.cn/example/xmle/note.xml";
NSURL* xmlUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData* xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:xmlUrl options: NSDataReadingUncached error: &err];
```

Comment: I met this question,too.Had you solve this question?